# how to zip all pdf files under a static folder? django

Tags: python, django, pdf, zip, compression

I have a folder named `pdfs` under `static` folder.

I am trying to have a returned zip which contains all the pdf files in the `pdfs` folder.

I have tried a few threads and used their codes, but I tried to workout things but then couldn't solve the last part that I get a message saying no file / directory

I know static folders are a bit different than usual folders.

can someone please give me a hand and see what I have missed?

Thanks in advance

```
    from StringIO import StringIO
    import zipfile

    pdf_list = os.listdir(pdf_path)
    print('###pdf list################################')
    print(pdf_path)  # this does show me the whole path up to the pdfs folder
    print(pdf_list)  # returns ['abc.pdf', 'efd.pdf']

    zip_subdir = "somefiles"
    zip_filename = "%s.zip" % zip_subdir

    # Open StringIO to grab in-memory ZIP contents
    s = StringIO()

    # Grab ZIP file from in-memory, make response with correct MIME-type
    resp = HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip')
    # ..and correct content-disposition
    resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % zip_filename

    # The zip compressor
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(s, "w")
    for pdf_file in pdf_list:
        print(pdf_file)

        zf.write(pdf_file, pdf_path + pdf_file)


    zf.writestr('file_name.zip', pdf_file.getvalue())
    zf.close()

    return resp
```

here I am getting errors for not able to find file / directory for 'abc.pdf'

P.S. I don't really  need any sub folders zipped into the zip file.  As long as all files are inside the zip, it'll be all good. (There won't be any sub folders in the `pdfs` folder)

Comment: not really a django thing, as much as a pure Python thing.  Maybe im a bit old school, but i would just do something like:   `os.system("zip -r -X %s/%s %s" % (zip_subdir, zip_filename, " ".join(pdf_list)))`

Comment: @Fallenreaper where should I place the code you provided though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself and made it into a function with comments.
complicated things myself earlier

```
# two params
# 1. the directory where files want to be zipped
# e.g. of file directory is /et/ubuntu/vanfruits/vanfruits/static/pdfs/
# 2. filename of the zip file
def render_respond_zip(self, file_directory, zip_file_name):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + zip_file_name

    # open a file, writable
    zip = ZipFile(response, 'w')

    # loop through the directory provided
    for single_file in os.listdir(file_directory):
        # open the file, full path to the file including file name and extension is needed as first param
        f = open(file_directory + single_file, 'r')

        # write the file into the zip with
        # first param is the name of the file inside the zip
        # second param is read the file
        zip.writestr(single_file, f.read())

    zip.close()

    return response
```